# Is it possible to use openjdk by excluding JIT shipped with it?

Tags: java, jit, coredump, adoptopenjdk

Need this to check whether JIT is causing crash during execution as below:

```
Unhandled exception
Type=Illegal instruction vmState=0x00000000
J9Generic_Signal_Number=00000048 Signal_Number=00000004 Error_Value=00000000 Signal_Code=00000002
```

Comment: Yes.  See dup link.  However, beware that you application will run an order of magnitude slower ....

Comment: FYI: (a) *GraalVM* with AOT (ahead of time compilation), and (b) *Project Leyden*, https://adtmag.com/articles/2020/04/29/leyden-addresses-java-pain-points.aspx